# Action do formulário para mesma página ou página diferente?

Tags: php, html, formulário

Na criação de um formulário em HTML com inserção no banco de dados, pode-se apontar o `action` do formulário para a própria página ou para outro script PHP. Estou em dúvida sobre qual seria a melhor opção.

Eu sempre uso uma segunda página, e faço a validação na segunda página também, caso a senha estiver errada (por exemplo, caso seja um formulário de login), eu exibo um aviso e redireciono para a página anterior.

Seria vantajoso eu fazer de outra maneira? Qual é são as diferenças entre as duas opções?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe "boa prática", "certo" ou "errado". Use como achar melhor. Se submeter para a mesma página, precisa redirecionar se passar na validação; se submeter para outra página, precisa guardar na seção os erros de validação, e redirecionar se não passar.

O que é muito comum é ter um único arquivo PHP como ponto de entrada (ou *front controller*) de toda a aplicação/site – geralmente um `index.php`. Nesse caso, os formulários costumam ser submetidos para ele mesmo. Talvez venha daí a impressão de que isso é o "correto".

Answer (score 2):

Sobre "certo" ou "errado", realmente é algo que não existe, neste contexto. Porém, é uma boa prática separar o PHP do HTML, para isto então, normalmente, é submetendo para outra página, onde você poderá validar os dados. Isto facilitará para uma futura modificação que outro programador fará, ou até mesmo você.

Mas cada caso é um caso, se você está trabalhando com um formulário apenas e este não é muito grande, joga tudo no mesmo arquivo e resolve tudo nele mesmo. Agora se for um sistema com vários módulos vai pela 1ª dica, separar HTML de PHP.